# Crystal Reports eliminating all data with a Null value when it is added to a report

Tags: sql, database, null, crystal-reports, isnull

I've got a report that has always worked. Basically, the report runs against the database using Catapult (back office PC system for our retail stores). The purpose of the report is to get a file that has some basic information that will be pulled for labels later.

I'm having an issue now. I wanted to find a way to add a "Promo Price" field to this report. To do this, I pulled in another table (view) from our database and linked the tables to allow me to show the "Promo Price" (DIS_Description). Now, I place the field (DIS_Description) in the report and run it. It works perfectly to show me the Promo Price field for records that actually have a Promo Price (again, managed in Catapult itself). But, for records that have no value to the DIS_Description, they won't be shown at all. I'm not **filtering** the report, so I can't simply throw a "OR ISNULL({DIS_Description})" to fix this.

Is there a way to show records that don't have a value for this field? I've even tried creating the following formula and using that in the report instead of the DIS_Description field itself:

IF ISNULL({DIS_Description})

THEN ""

ELSE {DIS_Description}

This still returns no data unless the field has a value. The second that I remove that field from the report, it shows everything as it should. Any ideas here?

Comment: Have you tried changing the default settings for NULLS? in formula workshop see where it says "exception for nulls" and change it so that nulls are zeros. would that solve the problem?

Comment: Sounds like maybe that field you added may have ended up in the table join?

Comment: Dave Kelly, I'm not sure where I'm supposed to change it for nulls = 0...I see where it says "Exceptions For Nulls", but the only thing that I can change it to is "Default Values for Nulls"

Comment: If you change it to default values , then strings will become '' and int will be 0

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was poking around with the table links, and I think I figured it out. The join was an INNER JOIN (not 100% sure what the different types of joins mean). I tried changing it to the others. LEFT OUTER JOIN returned the same problems. I then tried RIGHT OUTER JOIN and it seems to be returning my data perfectly...

Anyone care to explain why? At least I have the answer now.

Comment: You need to be VERY careful with sql joins, specially when you dont know what they mean. Leaving your Inner Join as before, there is a setting in Report Options called as "Convert database NULL values to default types", may be thats not checked in your case.

Comment: The "left join" and "right join" do the same thing, only different in which table is used as the base table and which is the augmenting table. I'm calling the base table the one that is compared, and the augmenting table the one that might result in nulls where there is no data. Which table is the "left" and which is the "right" depends on what direction your arrow is pointing, which results from the direction you drag the column when linking. You drag from your "left" table and to your "right" table.